# How to upload CSV file with QuestDB with different time precision?

Tags: questdb

I have large CSVs with trade data in it and I want to upload them to QuestDB. One of the column is the transaction timestamp and I want it to be the designated timestamp on the column. The data in CSV has this transaction time sometimes with seconds precision and sometimes in microseconds e.g.

```
Transaction Timestamp
2021-01-03 12:45:56.234567
2021-01-03 12:45:57
```

Any way to upload this CSV with out rewriting the rows? I found how to set column `pattern` on upload here https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest but it seems to be impossible to have 2 slightly different `patterns` or have an optional part (microseconds in my case are optional)